# All text on Android.SE and its meta are showing up grayed out

Tags: bug, design

Basically all text on Android.SE and its child meta are showing up as gray when I use Google Chrome, but it appears fine on Firefox.

Chrome:

An answer:

[image]

Main page:

[image]

Meta:

[image]

Firefox:

Main:

[image]

Meta:

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu.

---

This is also a problem on Opera:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a local copy of the Roboto font?

Comment: (Please speak in layman's terms, as I always get lost when trying to read things like that. I have no idea what that means, sorry...)

Comment: Sorry. Is the Roboto font found within your `.local/share/fonts` folder?

Comment: Where would I locate this folder?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure because I'm not on Ubuntu. I did find [this question on Ask Ubuntu about installing fonts.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts)

Comment: +1: got the same problem here. Reinstalling Chrome doesn't help either. Strangely, on another freshly set-up PC it appears fine.

Comment: No repro on Chrome 59.0.3071.104 (current official build) on Windows 10.

Comment: @Shokhet OP said it's Ubuntu, a Linux distro, not Windows

Comment: I understood, @iBug. I was reporting that I couldn't reproduce the bug in Windows, in case that's useful to the developers.

Comment: Reproduced on Ubuntu 17.04.  Makes things very, very hard to read.

Comment: There's a possibility that the Roboto you're using is broken (refer to [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/google/roboto/issues/194#issuecomment-232771317)). You may need to update the font (refer to Hynes' comment or [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773326/))

Comment: I have the entire Roboto family installed and everything is still virtually unreadable: http://imgur.com/xzthyyV

Chrome 59.0.3071.115

Comment: I just removed, downloaded and installed the font. It still looks the same.

Comment: @RatherNotsay Uninstall the Roboto font family from your computer. Restart computer. Check your Chrome browser to see if it's solved.

Comment: I can confirm - the font is horrible in Chrome and works fine in Firefox. I have a local copy of Roboto installed and am using a Windows 10 laptop with an HD display. Font is also fine in Edge & IE.

Comment: I have this exact issue. Chrome: Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)
OS: Windows 10

Comment: @Mithrandir Open Font Viewer (press Super and start typing "font viewer"). Scroll down to R and see if you have the Roboto font.

Comment: @ArtOfCode - ah, thanks. Yes, I have it. It does appear to be a little gray.

Comment: windows 10, Chrome, completely unreadable:  http://imgur.com/a/0MLxj

Comment: Repro on Windows 10 as well, unusable

Comment: Using Google Chrome: unreadable. Using Microsoft Edge: perfectly clear. Using Internet Explorer 11: perfectly clear. Really I have to switch to those "browsers"?

Comment: I can reproduce it on Arch only if I have the [ttf-google-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ttf-google-fonts-git/) package installed. I already had a Roboto version from anopther font bundle and that didn't cause issues. Installing the ttf-google-fonts-git package makes the fonts break.

Comment: Still a problem in Windows 10 1703, Chrome 61.0.3163.100...

Comment: Looks fixed for me since today, nice ...

Answer (score 8):

I use Arch Linux, and have instaled ttf-google-fonts-git. Roboto has always been a part of the package. But the site still looks awful on my computer. When I was typing this as a comment, I couldn't see what I'm typing well enough. Though I can see this just fine when typing in the Answer section.

If you must use Roboto, please use Roboto-Medium or Roboto-Regular instead of thin or light variants. The site is currently unusable for me. And please set up fallbacks for people who don't have Roboto.

Comment: On Arch, I already had Roboto installed, as well as various other ttf fonts and it worked fine. I installed `ttf-google-fonts-git` and now I can reproduce the issue. Unless you *know* you need all the fonts in that (bloated) package, I suggest removing it and installing the notofonts bundle (which includes a load of fonts which work for most, if not all, languages) instead.

Comment: @terdon Installing or removing font packages to cater to specific websites seems like approaching the problem backwards. Websites should cater to a general userbase, and not require *removal* of packages that people find useful elsewhere. Where will this approach end? Install package `foo` to make website A legible, install conflicting package `bar` to make website B legible?

Comment: Oh absolutely! I am not suggesting that's a solution to what is undeniably a bug. I was just surprised since I couldn't reproduce it and noticed that you were using Arch, so I installed the package. Since installing it makes the bug appear and removing it fixes it, I figured I may as well let you know since that might be a decent workaround for you. And having seen your profile, I will bring back the original *scripts* I wanted to use instead of *languages* in my previous comment. The notofonts bundle works for all scripts I've tried and I've tried a good many.

Comment: @terdon Ah, I misunderstood. Apologies.

Answer (score 6):

Not a real answer to this, but I've experienced this font issue in at least 3 of my Windows 10 laptops/PCs.

Things common to all those PCs, if I remember correctly, were:

1. Windows 10, drivers, Chrome, and all software up to date.
2. Copy of Roboto font family (downloaded directly from Google) installed locally.
3. Font issue was noticeable not just on Android SE, but even on Google's sites using Roboto.

Issue was gone once I uninstalled the font family from my system. I suppose it was a Chrome-specific issue where the local Roboto family competed with the Google fonts' online version of it.

This could be relevant to Ubuntu as well.

Comment: That seems to be correct. I have Windows 10 + Chrome + local Roboto. Just uninstalled Roboto and this site is readable again.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Web Override](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-override/lllllobkincmdnjfkbknjacacmnlajll?hl=en-US) extension for Chrome to fix this.

[image]

Then just add the following to the CSS tab:

```
body,textarea,input {
    font-family: Arial !important; 
}
```

p.s. I *cannot believe* this has not been fixed...

Comment: Worked nicely on the text but not the comment box.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to confirm that this issue has been fixed today (2018-01-06) as seen from my 2 Windows devices. I have the Roboto font family installed locally and the issue had plagued Chrome until last night - logged in today and it looks normal again.

[image]